# A required bean can not be found during tests / No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, junit

I am developing a small app just to try Spring boot on my own. It has five different modules (eclipse projects):

> model--contains entity classes, DTO's and mappers to switch between them

> data--contains repositories

> service--contains services and their implementations

> reserve-management--contains the controller for the reservations and the spring app itself

> person-management--contains the controller for the people data and the spring app itself

If I start either of the apps, they run just fine but when developing tests for them I always get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
> ~[na:na]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
> ~[.cp/:na]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
> ~[.cp/:na]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
> ~[.cp/:na]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
> ~[.cp/:na]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
> ~[.cp/:na]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
> ~[.cp/:na]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'reservesServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'reserveRepo'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'com.hotel.data.reserve.ReservesRepository'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
> at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132)
> ~[spring-boot-test-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
> at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> ... 71 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'com.hotel.data.reserve.ReservesRepository'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> ... 90 common frames omitted

It also tells me that I should add a bean of type ReservesRepository in my configuration.

**I have removed methods from classes for brevity.**

Test class and pom.xml in **reserve-management** project:

```
    package com.hotel.reservemanagement.service;
    
    import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
    
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    
    import com.hotel.model.reserve.Reserve;
    import com.hotel.service.reserve.ReservesServiceImpl;
    
    @SpringBootTest(classes = ReservesServiceImpl.class)
    @ComponentScan("com.hotel.data")
    public class ReservesServiceTests {
        
        @Autowired
        private ReservesServiceImpl reservesService;
        
        @Test
        @Transactional
        void testSave () {
            Optional<Reserve> reserve = this.reservesService.findById(2L);
            reserve.get().setAdults(3L);
            this.reservesService.save(reserve.get());
            Optional<Reserve> reserveResult = this.reservesService.findById(2L);
            
            assertEquals(3L, reserveResult.get().getAdults());
        }
    }
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.1</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
            <groupId>com.hotel</groupId>
            <artifactId>reserve-management</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>reserve-management</name>
            <description>Hotel reserves management</description>
            <properties>
                <java.version>11</java.version>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
            
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency> 
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.hotel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>model</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.hotel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        
        </project>
```

Reserves service, its implementation and pom.xml in **service** project:

```
    package com.hotel.service.reserve;
    
    public interface ReservesService {
        //some code here    
    }
```

```
    package com.hotel.service.reserve;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import com.hotel.data.reserve.ReservesRepository;
    
    
    @Service
    public class ReservesServiceImpl implements ReservesService{
        
        @Autowired
        private ReservesRepository reserveRepo;
        //some code here
    }
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.hotel</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>service</name>
        <description>Services for Hotel application</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.hotel</groupId>
                <artifactId>data</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

Repository class and pom.xml in **data** project:

```
    package com.hotel.data.reserve;
    
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    
    import com.hotel.model.reserve.Reserve;
    
    @Repository
    public interface ReservesRepository extends JpaRepository<Reserve, Long> {
        //some code here
    }
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.hotel</groupId>
        <artifactId>data</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>data</name>
        <description>Data for Hotel application</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.hotel</groupId>
                <artifactId>model</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the test class and added `@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.hotel")` and now this test does work, which makes sense since I had not told anywhere where to look for the rest of the Spring beans.

Comment: is your application main class located so that all your components are in sub-packages compared to it? Could be that the `@ComponentScan` that is part of the `@SpringBootAppplication` can't see those components.

Comment: No, @Kris, they are not. They are in different projects in fact. But I have theese three anotations for the application main class:
`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.hotel")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.hotel")
@ComponentScan(basePackages= "com.hotel")`

Comment: Your answer contains another question. Instead, new questions should be asked separately. Please [edit] to remove the new question from the answer (and possibly add some additional explanation to the answer) and post the question separately if you want. Note that you can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Deleted new question and added a little bit more explanation. Thanks, @YurkoFlisk!